# xcWorkSpace arises issues in my code

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, avkit

My normal Xcode project compiles completely fine but since I am using pods, I must open the xcworkspace project. This causes the 2 bottom lines of my code to be errors.

```
var session = AVCaptureSession()

session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video)
```

The compiler states:

```
Type 'AVCaptureSession.Preset' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'photo'
```

and

```
 Type 'AVMediaType' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'video'
```

I don't understand why it thinks they are NSStrings all of a sudden. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you Build the project, clean the project, clean the build folder, and delete derived data? That might do it for you.

Comment: Yes, didn't change anything. Maybe I just need to create a new xcode project. I can't get anything to work.

Comment: I would remove the Xcode workspace and reinstall the pods.Let me know if that fixes it.